# Count the number of posts within categories

Tags: php

I have a little problem. I'm building a blog, and it is working. Now I want to add a menu with the categories. I have 2 tables in the same database `blog_posts` and `blog_categories`. In the table `blog_categories`, there are 2 rows: id and name. Id is also in the `blog_posts`table. The categories are displayed on the page, using a while loop. But I want to display the number of posts that are in that categorie after the categorie name.

It would look like this:
Cat1: 1
Cat2: 4
Cat3: 2

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe something like `select count(*), cat from blog_posts as bp join blog_categories as bc on bp.catid = bc.id group by bp.catid`

Comment: Could you please explain that statement a little more?

Comment: `count(*)` counts the number of unique rows being returned, `cat` is the name of the category, `join` joins the two tables together, `on` tells how the tables are related, `group by` puts all the rows of the same type together.

Comment: So the only thing I need to do is change cat to the category name which I want to count the posts of?

Comment: Probably the columns that associate the relation of the 2 tables (if I guessed that right though let me know, I should probably buy a lottery ticket).. and the `group by`'s column name. The SQL structure is probably the only part that is right.

Comment: What user378… is saying, is that you should probably read up on SQL `JOIN` syntax, for example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). Note that depending on the database you use (MySQL, SQLite, …) the syntax may vary.

Comment: All right, so: in this piece of code: `SELECT COUNT(*), cat FROM blog_posts AS bp join blog_categories AS bc on bp.catid = bc.id GROUP BY bp.catid` what do I need to change to get this working?

Comment: You're asking us to reach into a black hole. Please add your table structures, and/or add a sqlfiddle. Also tag the DB you are using so we use the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

**Tables:**

```
 blog_posts(id, title, catid, .... )
 blog_categories(id, title, ... )
```

**PDO:**

```
$sql=$dbh->query("SELECT blog_categories.*, COUNT(blog_posts.CatID) AS count FROM blog_categories LEFT JOIN blog_posts ON blog_posts.CatID=blog_categories.ID GROUP BY blog_categories.ID ORDER BY count DESC"); 
while($row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { 
   echo $row->title.':'.$count;
}
```

**Result:**

```
Cat 2: 5
Cat 1: 3
Cat 3: 1
```

Comment: Looks nice, how would the rest of the code look like?

Comment: This answer is perfect. The query inside the PDO statement is great and will work. This is exactly how you should write it for your query. Well done @margelani.