# View total items related to the desired category

Tags: php, sql

Database structure:

Name: **Top Category**

1. Displays 5 main categories on the site (main menu)

Name: **Mid Category**

1. Displays sub-categories (drop-down menu) that are related to the selected category (Top Category)

Name: **End Category**

1. Displays sub categories from the sub-category (drop-down menu) that are related to the selected sub-category (Mid Category) of the first category (Top Category)

If the user looks at the navigation they will have 4-5 categories from the main menu to choose which have sub-categories and certain subcategories have their own subcategories. What I need, that is, where I have a problem now, is the following. If the Sneakers category has 10 sub-categories (Adidas, Nike, reebok ...) and 4 sub-categories for the sub-category (Nike -> AirMax 180, TN ...), With the code I printed below, I get a view of all MID-Categories saved in the database but I have a problem with displaying the number of items related to the MID-Category. What is the best way to define MID-Category-related items?

The code that is currently useful for display looks like this:

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT
        // Display product information
        t1.p_id,
        t1.p_name,
        t1.p_old_price,
        t1.p_current_price,
        t1.p_qty,
        t1.p_featured_photo,
        t1.p_is_featured,
        t1.p_is_active,
        t1.ecat_id,
        // t2. is End Category in this case that will be ( AirMax 180, Tn ...)
        t2.ecat_id,
        t2.ecat_name,
        // t3. is Mid Category in this case that will be (Nike, Reebook, Addidas...)
        t3.mcat_id,
        t3.mcat_name,
        // t4. is Top Category in this case that will be ( Shoes, Jacket, Socks...)
        t4.tcat_id,
        t4.tcat_name

        FROM tbl_product t1
        JOIN tbl_end_category t2
        ON t1.ecat_id = t2.ecat_id
        JOIN tbl_mid_category t3
        ON t2.mcat_id = t3.mcat_id
        JOIN tbl_top_category t4
        ON t3.tcat_id = t4.tcat_id
        ORDER BY t1.p_id DESC
    ");
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $i++;
?>
<h6><a href="product-category.php?id=<?php echo $row['mcat_id']; ?>&type=mid-category"><?php echo $row['mcat_name']; ?></a></h6>
<span>
    <?php 
         // Here I should enter a code that will show the total number of items related to the category shown.
    ?>
</span>
<?php
    }
?>
```

I want the user to look at the Nike category to see below the Nike name how many items we have related to the Nike category.

I found some answers on StackOverflow ( [Count the number of posts within categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031071/count-the-number-of-posts-within-categories) ) but any help on how this can be implemented with my code, maybe that will resolve my issue.

Comment: Why didn't you just use some variable as counter?

Comment: The problem is that in order to get how many items are related to the sub-category (Nike), I have to extract the id from (end-category) which is related to (mid-category) where it is connected (Nike) and which is related to (Top Category) Shoes. @Sevada797